# How to inform Google about a "definition"?

Tags: html, seo, google-search, semantic-markup

When I google for *"[define high-efficiency](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20high-efficiency)"*, it shows a web definition linking to a glossary:

> [image: Screenshot from Google search query "define high-efficiency"]

How does Google know that this is a *definition*?

Initially I'd thought that the [`<dt>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt) and [`<dd>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dd) tags were used, but the html code for the page http://www.mascordefficientliving.com/content/faq-glossary.asp does not use any `<dt>` `<dd>` tags.

What is the HTML code used to inform Google (and other search engines) that we are writing a *definition*?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde. It's about html, though probably seo-related.

Answer (score -1):

That is propably done by semantic code. Have a look into that here: https://schema.org/docs/gs.html

Comment: I checked that site and didn't see one for definitions

Comment: That depends on the particular case.

Comment: i.E. a Medical Expression by https://schema.org/MedicalEntity
or a place https://schema.org/Place

...it all depends on the content.

Answer (score -1):

Well - I looked it up and tried to get the google result. This is a feature google.de didn't roll out yet. And I fear this is nothing a website owner can influence. Since the feature must be done by algorithm.

But I am sure semantic markup will help your case do get such a definition reference IF your site reputation is ok too.

Comment: Do you have examples of *which* semantic markup do you mean in particular?

Comment: I answered that above

Comment: Google’s `define:` search operator is pretty old and also works on google.de ([example](https://www.google.de/search?q=define:buffer+overflow)). Would also work by searching for `definiere …`. See [documentation](http://www.google.com/intl/de/help/features_list.html#definition).